# Failed opening './admin/main.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php')

Tags: php, include, include-path

Getting following error

> Failed opening './admin/main.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php')

The file with include is in the `/admin` directory. Same site works fine on 2 other hosting I tried, but on that one (godaddy) it doesn't work and throws the error.
If I change the path to `../admin/main.inc` it works, but I can't afford changing all the files with includes in script, so I'm asking for a help here. If you can tell me ho to fix that issue or at least what should I say to support so they can fix it?

All I found on internet was "PHP on your Host is not configured to include the current directory"

Update:

Ok now I got it working, but... here is the situation. Folder named /admin there index.php and forgot.php (forgot password). Both files include /admin/main.inc Here is index.php include

```
`include_once "../admin/main.inc";`
```

Here is forgot.php include

```
`include_once "./admin/main.inc";`
```

You see one file use ../ and another ./ and they both include same file. Here main.inc

```
`session_start();
require_once '../class/class_db.php';
require_once '../class/class_wwf.php';
require_once '../class/class_other.php';
require_once '../admin/class/class_auth.php';`
```

So the idea is if it stays this way, index.php works fine but forgot.php returns failed to include, no such file...

If I change main.inc to use ./ index.php stops working and forgot.php works...

Comment: I think you found a right thing. Consider contacting your hosting provider

Comment: Why can't you afford to change it to `'../admin/main.inc'` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is should go to GoDaddy customer support.

Answer (score 2):

> If you can tell me ho to fix that issue or at least what should I say to support so they can fix it? All I found on internet was "PHP on your Host is not configured to include the current directory"

Okay first of all an explanation what you face: Your includes start with either `./` or `../`. These paths for includes are relative to the current working directory.

That is *normally* the directory the php-file that is being requested resides in however, technically this is independent.

So technically you have the hidden dependency of the working directory here. If you don't want to change the include paths, change the working directory.

However, it is normally easier to do a search and replace over multiple files and replace the `./` starts with `__DIR__ . '/`, that is the [magic `__DIR__` constant](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined) that represents the directory of the current file, it is independent to the working directory setting.

---

> All I found on internet was "PHP on your Host is not configured to include the current directory"

That normally means something different and actually this is even not the case on your hoster. On your Host, it *is* configured to include the current directory:

> ... include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php'

The first dot in the include path *is* the current working directory.

Comment: Yep, chdir('..'); before include makes this ./ thing work :)

Comment: Updated first post. Please check it. @RauliRajande

Answer (score 0):

If it works with .. then you can dynamically extend default include path with parent directory:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../');
```

(It has to be before include statement, preferably somewhere in the beginning of the script and php has to have rights to read this directory.)

Edit: seems that ./ in the beginning of filename effectively blocks this, so you can try:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__DIR__));
```

... or remove all ./ from the include filenames, your application should work without these.